# Orange only randomizing on right side of screen python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So every single time my player collides with my orange or my orange collides with my platform, my orange will only slightly randomize to the right, I'm trying make it randomize everywhere on the screen but it is not working. I made tried to make my orange go back up the screen when it collided with my player or platform then go back down and reapt the steps again.
The randomizer code that's not working.

```
run = True
while run:
[...]

for Orange in oranges:
        Orange.y += playerman.speed
    for Orange in oranges:
        for Platform in platforms:
            if Orange.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect) or Orange.rect.colliderect(playerman.rect):
                Orange.speed += 1
                Orange.x = random.randint(Orange.rect.x,Orange.rect.x + Orange.rect.width)
                Orange.y = random.randrange(0, 1 + 12)
```

My full code

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500 ))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")

BG = pygame.image.load("b_g1.png")

S = pygame.image.load("Score.png")
S = pygame.transform.scale(S,(S.get_width()//10, S.get_height()//10))

C = pygame.mixer.Sound("Crunch.ogg")

SL = pygame.mixer.Sound("Slurp.ogg")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.right = [pygame.image.load("Player_runright1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright4.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright5.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright6.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright7.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runright8.png")]
        
        self.left = [pygame.image.load("Player_runleft1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft4.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft5.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft6.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft7.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_runleft8.png")]
        
        self.idle = [pygame.image.load("Player_idle1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle3.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle4.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle5.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle6.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle7.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_idle8.png"),]
        
        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_idlel1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel4.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel5.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel6.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel7.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_idlel8.png")]


        self.jump = [pygame.image.load("Player_jump1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump3.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump4.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump6.png")]

        self.ljump = [pygame.image.load("Player_leftjump1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_leftjump2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_leftjump3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_leftjump4.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_leftjump5.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_leftjump6.png")]
        self.direction = "ljump"
        self.direction = "jump"
        self.direction = "idlel"
        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()+40, image.get_height()+40)) for image in self.right]
        self.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()+40, image.get_height()+40)) for image in self.left]
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()+40, image.get_height()+40)) for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()+40, image.get_height()+40)) for image in self.idlel]
        self.jump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()+40, image.get_height()+40)) for image in self.jump]
        self.ljump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()+40, image.get_height()+40)) for image in self.ljump]

        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        if self.direction == "right":
            image_list = self.right
        if self.direction == "left":
            image_list = self.left
        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
        if self.direction == "jump":
            image_list = self.jump
        if self.direction == "ljump":
            image_list = self.ljump
        # is it time to show next frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
            # time till next frame
            inter_time_delay = 1000 // self.fps
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
            # show next frame
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0

        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect(), 2 )
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 13
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)

        
            
            
        



class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.grass = pygame.image.load("Grass_1.png")
        self.grass = pygame.transform.scale(self.grass,(self.grass.get_width()-30, self.grass.get_height()-30))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        platform_rect = self.grass.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        platform_rect.centerx += 5
        platform_rect.centery += 3
        window.blit(self.grass,platform_rect)


class Platform2:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.grass = pygame.image.load("Grass_2.png")
        self.grass = pygame.transform.scale(self.grass,(self.grass.get_width()-25, self.grass.get_height()-25))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        platform2_rect = self.grass.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        platform2_rect.centerx += 0.1
        platform2_rect.centery -= 0
        window.blit(self.grass,platform2_rect)



######## ALL FRUITS


class Orange:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.orange = pygame.image.load("Orange_1.png")
        self.orange = pygame.transform.scale(self.orange,(self.orange.get_width()//25, self.orange.get_height()//25))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft =(self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


        orange_rect = self.orange.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        orange_rect.centerx -= 1
        orange_rect.centery += 2
        window.blit(self.orange,orange_rect)


        

# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)


### DRAWing CLASSES
# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(300,255,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(2200,465,35,35.1,white)

# drawing platform2
Platform1 = Platform2(2300,465,35,35.1,white)

# Drawing Orange
orange1 = Orange(-150,200,25,25,white)




### LIST
# Platform List
platforms = [platform1]

# Platform2 list
Platforms = [Platform1]

# Orange list
oranges = [orange1]








# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    window.blit(BG,(0,0))

    # for Food
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    
    # Drawing the player the screen
    playerman.draw()
    # Drawing Platform to the screen
    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()

    # Drawing Platform2 to the screen
    for Platform2 in Platforms:
        Platform2.draw()

    # Drawing Orange to the screen
    for Orange in oranges:
        Orange.draw()



font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
score = 0
text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((150,40))


platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"1                  1",
"1         o        1",
"1                  1",
"1     o   o        1",
"1            o     1",
"1                  1",
"1                  1",
"1                  1",
"1    o             1",
"1                  1",
"1                  1",
"11       11       11",
"22111111122111111122",
"22222222222222222222",]
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platform = Platform(ix*35, iy*36.4, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
            platforms.append(new_platform)
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "2":
            new_platform2 = Platform2(ix*35, iy*36.3, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
            Platforms.append(new_platform2)
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "2":
            new_platform2 = Platform2(ix*35, iy*36.3, 35,35.1,(255, 255, 255))
            Platforms.append(new_platform2)
# FRUITS
for iy, row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "o":
            new_orange = Orange(ix*35, iy*60, 25,25,(255, 255, 255))
            oranges.append(new_orange)





x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
    # orange falling and colliding with platform
    for Orange in oranges:
        Orange.y += playerman.speed
    for Orange in oranges:
        for Platform in platforms:
            if Orange.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect) or Orange.rect.colliderect(playerman.rect):
                Orange.speed += 1
                Orange.x = random.randint(Orange.rect.x,Orange.rect.x + Orange.rect.width)
                Orange.y = random.randrange(0, 1 + 12)

    


    for Orange in oranges:
        for one in range(len(oranges)-1,-1,-1):
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(oranges[one].rect):
                score += 1
                text = font.render(" = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
                textRect.center = ((150,40))
                C.play()


                






    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = -7
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 7

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 0

            x += x_change
            if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
                x = old_x

           
    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
            px -= playerman.speed
            playerman.direction = "left"
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 700 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        px += playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "right"

    else:      
        if playerman.direction == "right":
            playerman.direction = "idle"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "left":
                playerman.direction = "idlel"
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
        py -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and py <500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        py += playerman.speed


    # animation for player jump
    if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            playerman.direction = "jump"
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left":
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.direction = "ljump"

    # player colliding with sides of pllatform
    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)


    
    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px


  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    window.blit(S,(50,0))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.randrange` works similar to `range`. The size of your screen is 700x500. Hence the range for the x coordinate is [0, `700-Orange.rect.width`] and the range for the y coordinates is [0, `500-Orange.rect.height`]:

```py
Orange.x = random.randrange(0, 700-Orange.rect.width)
Orange.y = random.randrange(0, 500-Orange.rect.height)
```